# Generating a Core Dump File of a child process

Tags: php, linux, crash-dumps, coredump, gnupg

I'm trying to run gpg from my php script using exec(). But it chashes with segmentation fault:
"gpg: Segmentation fault caught ... exiting"
It crashes within a child process so my php script works ok. To identify a problem I wanna get a core file.
I tried to run

```
ulimit -c unlimited
echo 1 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
```

I added  "* soft core unlimited" to /etc/security/limits.conf but no core files have been created.

I would be very thankful for any advice or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

From the output message, it seems gpg catches the exception (is this true?).

You can try the `gcore` command if applicable. Otherwise, if the source code is available (which I assume is, as you are debugging it), you may use, for example, google-coredumper. Not sure if this is sufficient for you though.

Comment: I have the sources but I can't understand how google-coredumper may help me. It's able to dump in certain place in the code but I don't know that certain place where it crashes.

Comment: @sfoid Another option is to try to run it with valgrind, which may point out the error. Looks like a tricky problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can start to think that your problem can be gpg catch some exceptions or PERMISSION issues.
Check it first.

Hope this help